# ColorChooser by clicking JMenu Item

Tags: java, oracle, swing, jmenuitem, jcolorchooser

I tried codes from different site's and one from here about a color. How do I get color chooser to work with the press of a jmenu item?

I looked at [ColorChooser Example](http://java.about.com/od/UsingDialogBoxes/ss/Color-Chooser-Program.htm) and also [Oracle Color Chooser Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html) and then implementing into the original class using the following code:

```
   JMenuItem clr = new JMenuItem("Font Color");
    clr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            ColorChooserDemo ccd = new ColorChooserDemo();
            ccd.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

But this seems do do nothing when I press the menu item.

The class code is from the oracle webpage. These are the following class I use (shortened of course to the problem at hand). I'm making a notepad program as i'm getting back into programming and refreshing my memory of how to do things in java. Problem at hand is, I am unable to get the color chooser to come up when I click on the jmenuitem clr (which is font color) the following code show's what I have so far:

Color Chooser Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.*;

/* ColorChooserDemo.java requires no other files. */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ColorChooserDemo extends JPanel
                              implements ChangeListener {

    protected JColorChooser tcc;
    protected JLabel banner;

    public ColorChooserDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //Set up color chooser for setting text color
        tcc = new JColorChooser();
        tcc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
        tcc.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                                             "Choose Text Color"));

        add(tcc, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        Color newColor = tcc.getColor();
        FirstWindow.ta1.setForeground(newColor);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ColorChooserDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new ColorChooserDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main Class:

import java.awt.EventQueue;

```
public class Main{
    protected static Object fw;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try
                {
                    FirstWindow fw = new FirstWindow();
                    fw.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
    }
}
```

FirstWindow class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FirstWindow extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected JColorChooser tcc;
    protected static JTextArea ta1;

    public FirstWindow() {
        super("Note Pad");

        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);

        //Setting the size of the note pad
        setSize(650, 745);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create the MenuBar
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(mb);

        //Create the panel to hold everything in
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        //Create the Text Area
        final JTextArea ta1 = new JTextArea();
        ta1.setFont(font);
        ta1.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        ta1.setLineWrap(true);
        ta1.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        //Create the Scroll Pane to hold the Text Area 
        final JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta1);
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(625,675));
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        //Create the menu's
        JMenu format = new JMenu("Format");

            //Create menu item for picking font color
        JMenuItem clr = new JMenuItem("Font Color");
        clr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ColorChooserDemo ccd = new ColorChooserDemo();
                ccd.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        //adding the menu items to the file menu tab

        //adding menu items to the edit tab

        //adding menu items to the format tab
        format.add(clr);

        //adding the menus to the menu bar
        mb.add(format);


        //adding the scroll pane to the panel
        p.add(sp);
        add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"I was wondering if it is possible to implement it from an action when you click on the JMenuItem."*  Of course it is possible.  As an aside, this 'question' contains no '?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to show the ColorChooser is the following:

In the ColorChooserDemo class, you have the method `private static void createAndShowGUI()`, which you should declare public.

Then, replace the ActionListener for the menu item to the following:

```
    clr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            ColorChooserDemo.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
```

Your ColorChooserDemo class extends JPanel, not JFrame. You first need a JFrame, then add the panel, then show the JFrame. This is what happens in the `createAndShowGUI()` method.

Edit:
I understood that you only wanted to know how to show the ColorChooserDemo when selecting a menu item.

However, to actually set the color, you might want to skip using your own ColorChooserDemo class, and replace the ActionListener code with the following:

```
    clr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Color c = JColorChooser.showDialog(ta1, "ColorChooserDemo", null);
            ta1.setForeground(c);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I also tried this but gives an error due to it trying to set the color of the JTextArea in the FirstWindow class.

Answer (score 0):

An [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) is easier not only for us to provide a solution, as Andrew suggested, but it may also help you figure out and understand what to do. Anyway, here's a quick example of opening a colour chooser after pressing a `JMenuItem`:

```
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JColorChooser jColorChooser = new JColorChooser();

        JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
        jDialog.setContentPane(jColorChooser);
        jDialog.pack();
        jDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

LE: (sorry, new to colour choosers myself) or just use [JColorChooser.showDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Color%29)

Comment: I have tried this and added public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent){...} at the end of the class and jColorChooser.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(listener); into that ActionListener but will not work. Without the ActionListener it sets the color but only after you click the menu item twice and wont change the color while clicking the colors inside the JColorChooser.